# Django: User object's 'email' attribute

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, authentication, twitter

I'm working on an application where users can log in into my application using their Twitter account credentials which I implemented using the `python-social-auth`. Now, Django's authentication system provides `User` objects, with five primary attributes of `username`, `password`, `email`, `first_name` and `last_name` as given in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Now, after the user successfully logs in using his/her Twitter account, I want certain fields of my form, like the user's full name, email address, Twitter account username, etc to be pre-filled. For that purpose, I used something like this for pre-filling user's full name form field:

```
{% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}

   Full Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "{{user.get_full_name}}"">

{% endif %}
```

This is what the above form field looks like after a user successfully logs in through his/her Twitter account:

[image]

Perfect! Works just as intended. Similarly, attributes such as `username`, `last_name`, `first_name` works just fine for the currently logged in `User` object.

However, when I try to pre-fill the email address field in my form using:

```
Email Address: <input type = "text" name = "email" value = "{{user.email}}"">
```

However, the value of `{{user.email}}` doesn't return anything, and my form field looks something like this:

[image]

Why is the `email` attribute of the `User` object not returning the email address through which the user logged in using his Twitter credentials? All other `User` attributes seem to be working just fine. Any reasoning behind this?

EDIT 1:

This is what my database at the admin looks like:

[image]

So the `email` field is empty, hence the `User` object returns nothing for that attribute value. But why is the email address not stored in the database every time a new user logs in using their Twitter accounts?

Comment: Are you sure you get the email address from the user? I would check what's in your db first.

Comment: you probably are getting the authentication signal from the auth backend you're using but it doesn't auto save to the database some how, so you can authenticate with the users email but you don't actually have it stored maybe?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson I have edited my original post. The problem lies exactly where you had anticipated. Any solutions?

Comment: @KyleL. Yes, the email address of the user doesn't get stored in the database for some reason. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 1):

The email is stored elsewhere when using python-social-auth. They create a [SocialUser](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/storage.html#social-user) table and likely the data you seek is stored in JSON format in the `extra_data` field - look at the [model](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py) created by PSA

Pulling the additional info may not be as trivial as before, but you can add functionality that will save the email address to your user's table when the social user is created. See [Pipeline](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline)

Comment: The 'extra_data' field doesn't contain the the email address data.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi The point of my answer was to tell you that you need to investigate how and where you are collecting your data. Is the email being returned during the twitter login? have you checked to see what the API call is returning? if no email is returned, then no email will exist. Look at the API call, then look at the Pipeline to decide what 'extra_data' is going to be stored. All of this is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

In admin if user_email is not showing probably there is no email added with perticular user.

Just make sure this by checking database again.

Comment: I have edited my original post. The email address field in the database is empty just like you anticipated. Any reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening probably because you have nothing in your register process that actually stores the email in the database for the form, so in your view have something like

```
p = #user object from form. 
p.email = request.POST['email']
p.save()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The 'email' attribute' still doesn't store any value.